# Find value between two given numbers - Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have created a software in Microsoft Visual Basic. I only need the last thing and that is to make the software to search trough a document and find values between two given numbers. I am printing out log files from smoke detectors and when you have over a thousand of them then it's more easy to just scan the log file.

Every smoke detector have a "box" of information but it's the information "verdi=" that is interesting.

Example:

```
Adresse 01.001  sone 0007
SFU.3ETG.TRAPP 1
r›ykdetektor, optisk    Dc
verdi=23  F›lsomhets modus=5
Dato=2009/00 Godkj.=35 Drift=16

Adresse 01.002  sone 0007
SFU.3ETG.GANG V/TRAPP 1
r›ykdetektor, optisk    Dc
verdi=23  F›lsomhets modus=5
Dato=2009/00 Godkj.=35 Drift=18
```

Here you can see that both of these smoke detectors have a value on 23 "verdi=23". So I want the software to simply make a list of all the values within two given numbers, ex; lower value "verdi=30" and upper value "verdi=40".

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Public Class choosedocument

    Private Sub MenuStrip1_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub UndoToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UndoToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Undo()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RedoToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RedoToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Redo()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CutToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Cut()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CopyToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Copy()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PasteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.Paste()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SelectAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        On Error GoTo E
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim readit As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        RichTextBox1.Text = readit.ReadToEnd
        readit.Close()
        Exit Sub
E:
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        On Error GoTo E
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim writeit As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        writeit.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
        writeit.Close()
        Exit Sub
E:
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Scan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles scanbutton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: oh dear.... that's going to annoy a lot of people....

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. Mistagged as C# instead of VB, and no evidence of a problem needing solving, just a request for someone to do the work on behalf of the OP.

Comment: I do have it in javascript so it can run through cmd but I try to make it more user friendly. I don't need someone to do it but maybe someone knows some codes that can be useful. I am new to this so I am just seeking some advise :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I got the answer from someone and thought it would be good to put it here.

```html
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            string start = "verdi=" + lowervaluebox.Text;
            string end = "verdi=" + uppervaluebox.Text;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(
                string.Join("",
                File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                .Where(x => x.CompareTo(start) >= 0
                    && x.CompareTo(end) <= 0)
                .Select(x => x + "\n")
                .ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("input_file.txt")

Dim allReadings As List(Of String) = allLines.Where(Function(line) line.Contains("verdi")).[Select](Function(line) line.Split(New [String]() {"verdi="}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(" "C)(0)).ToList()
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. Did this work? Feedback would be nice.

Comment: Nice one-liner! Just the min and max filtering is missing :-)

Comment: I got to this one but I try to find out how to choose lower value and upper value. Ex; lower value 23 and upper value 30. 

Private Sub Scan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles scanbutton.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim allReadings As List(Of String) = allLines.Where(Function(line) line.Contains("verdi")).[Select](Function(line) line.Split(New [String]() {"verdi="}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(" "c)(0)).ToList()
    End Sub